# Dell E6410 won't wake from sleep

Tags: windows-7, sleep, dell-latitude

I have a work-issued Dell Latitude E6410, it's battery life is pretty pathetic, so I've been putting it to sleep during the lulls in meetings, but when it comes time for me to start using my laptop again, it seems to wake up, but the screen remains black and my laptop becomes unresponsive: turning scroll-lock on doesn't work; neither does putting it back to sleep.

I've looked around a bit and it seems that the best thing to do is see about updating the BIOS, but since it's a work-issued laptop and not mine, I don't feel comfortable doing that.

Should I just inform my supervisor that I can't wake my laptop from sleep or is there some setting that I can change that will resolve the issue?

EDIT:

I have BIOS vA16; the issue happens regardless of whether I'm running off AC or Battery power.

Comment: Possibly a driver error. Depending on how IT imaged the machine the default windows driver could be causing the error. I had this issue with Windows 7 and 10 where it would not wake from sleep. I found the video driver the cause and updated it direct from the manufacturer site which for me was NVidia.

Comment: Just try Ctrl-Alt-Delete and your username/password. Sometimes the computer is still waiting for your input, despite the screen not showing anything. @tree made a great suggestion though.

Comment: Disabling Intel SpeedStep in the BIOS under some versions of said BIOS seems to resolve the issue, but on my machine it just causes the system to crash (it literally just turns off: think removing the battery kind of power down).  Source: [Latitude E6410 resume from S3 Suspend (on batteries)](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/p/19351240/19774660)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf, pressing Ctrl-Alt-Delete doesn't do anything; my system's still frozen.  Good idea, though.

Comment: Right, but if your IT department is even slightly worth their salt, they'll have enabled password on wake. Meaning, you may need to press Ctrl-Alt-Delete to get to the password screen. You may not see it, but it could still be there.

Comment: @tree Updating my intel graphics card may have helped a little, I still can't seem to wake my computer without pressing one of the power buttons, which just makes it shutdown or restart, but at least it isn't frozen anymore.